# Add Access controller and content type in request header javascript

Tags: javascript, cors

I have functionality where i call a API url from my java script, for this i want to add CORS in my code, to do so i have tried the following codes nothing is working out, can anyone suggest how to add this in header.

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", "http://example.com:8080/method", false);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader(JSON.stringify({"Content-type" : "application/json", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "http://example.com:8080/method"}));
    xhttp.send(jsonParam);
    var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);



var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com:8080/method');
    xhttp.open("POST", "http://example.com:8080/method", false);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type" : "application/json");
    xhttp.send(jsonParam);
    var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CORS must be sent serverside, you can't manage it clientside.

There are few exceptions:

https://gist.github.com/jesperorb/6ca596217c8dfba237744966c2b5ab1e

Comment: I understood, here i had a question of sending token to API in request header and i tried adding request header with authentication token and content type, it was not working, what i understood from internet is we can add multiple request header lines.